# Margin for optimal decision plane

Tags: machine-learning, svm

```
For a given dataset of 2-D input data, we apply the SVM learning
algorithm and achieve an optimal decision plane:

H(x) = x^1 + 2x^2 + 3

What is the margin of this SVM?
```

I've been looking at this for hours trying to work out how to answer this. I think it's meant to be relatively simple but I've been searching through my learning material and cannot find how I'm meant to answer this.

I'd appreciate some help on the steps I should use to solve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is imposible to calculate the margin wit only given optimal decision plane. You should give the support vectors or at least samples of classes.

Anyway, you can follow this steps:

**1-** Calculate Lagrange Multipliers (alphas) I don' t know which environment you work on but you can use Quadratic Programming Solver of MATLAB: [`quadprog()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/quadprog.html), it is not hard to use.

**2-** Find support vectors. Remember, only alphas of support vectors don' t equal to zero (but other alphas of samples equal to zero) so you can find support vectors of classes.

**3-** Calculate `w` vector which is a vector orthogonal to optimal hyperplane. You know, can use the summation below to calculate this vector:

[image]

where,

```
alpha(i): alphas (lagrange multipliers) of support vector;    
y(i)    : labels of samples (say -1 or +1); 
phi()   : kernel function; 
x(i)    : support vectors.
```

**4-** Take one support vector from each class lets say one is `SV1` from class 1 and other `SV2` from class 2. Now you can calculate the margin using vector projection and dot product:

`margin = < (SV1 - SV2), w > / norm(w)`

where,

```
<(SV1 - SV2), w> : dot product of vector (SV1 - SV2) and vector w
norm(w)          : norm of vector w
```